# PERC RAID1 Hard Drives Access

Tags: raid-1

I have a dell poweredge r210 ii with two hard drives connected as RAID1 with PERC.
This server got some hardware issues which preventing from booting and now I want to access the data of these mirrored hard drives. Any solution you know?
I have HP workstation z600 and z800, can I use them for these hard drives?

Comment: Which controller do you have?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator In Dell Poweredge it is PERC built-in and dont have any other controller. In HP workstation i don't know whether it is having or not any controller.

Comment: Look up on Dell's website what controller it is. Use your service tag to get the specs for your system. There are different ones even for the built in models.